# Are there any tools that are able to do cyclomatics on Pro*C++ sources?

Tags: c++, cyclomatic-complexity, oracle-pro-c

Are there any tools that are able to do code metrics on Pro*C++ sources?

I haven't been able to find anything specific via Google.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pro*C can generate valid C++ files](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-proc.html#c++%20user), for code metrics tools on standard c++ [Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=cyclomatic+complexity+c%2B%2B&btnG=Search).

Comment: Yes, that is true.  However, the generated c++ files are not what we do maintenance on.  It is an interesting suggestion. I will pass it on.